# Exception : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to instantiate a Java bean, however it throws

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at com.application.jsf.BooksTable.getLastId(BooksTable.java:54)
    at com.application.jsf.BooksManager.<init>(BooksManager.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    ... 55 more
```

Here's the relevant code of `BooksManager` class:

```
private BooksTable booksTable;
private BookGenerator bookGenerator;

public BooksManager() {
    booksTable = new BooksTable();
    bookGenerator = new BookGenerator(booksTable.getLastId());
}
```

And the `BooksTable` class:

```
private ArrayList<BookBean> booksList;
private int BOOKS_ON_PAGE = 10;

BooksTable(){
    this.booksList = new ArrayList<BookBean>();
}

public int getLastId(){
    if(this.booksList == null){
        return -1;
    }
    return this.booksList.get(this.booksList.size()).getBookId();
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You got `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`. This has nothing to do with JSF at all. The exception is from `java.lang` package which indicates a basic Java SE problem. In the future, please pay more carefully attention to it. Isolate the problem in a plain Java application with `main()` method without all that JSF code noise. I've at least removed the irrelevant JSF noise from the question so that it's easier salvagable.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing:

```
public int getLastId(){
if(this.booksList == null){
    return -1;
}
return this.booksList.get(this.booksList.size()).getBookId();
}
```

to:

```
public int getLastId(){
if(this.booksList == null || this.booksList.size() == 0){
    return -1;
}
return this.booksList.get(this.booksList.size()-1).getBookId();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Reason :

```
     public int getLastId(){
         if(this.booksList == null){
           return -1;
         }
         return this.booksList.get(this.booksList.size()).getBookId(); //This line causing the problem when calling from BookManager
  }
```

add the one more validation in the if : this.bookList.size() == 0